# how to create a function in PowerPoint VSTO c# Add-in which will change the current slide to the next slide and how can I test it?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, vsto

I am trying to create a VSTO PowerPoint Add-in in c#, which will have a function which changes the current slide onto the next one.
I am new to VSTO Add-in and don't know how I can implement that and test it.
I need the function to be called and it has to move to the next slide.
It also has to find the active slideshow window

and I also can't understand, how can I test those functions. Should I call them inside ThisAddIn class?...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following ways:

- Use the [SlideShowView.Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slideshowview.next) method which displays the slide immediately following the slide that's currently displayed. If the last slide is displayed, the Next method closes the slide show in speaker mode and returns to the first slide in kiosk mode.

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
```

- Use the [SlideShowView.GotoSlide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slideshowview.gotoslide) method which switches to the specified slide during a slide show. You can specify whether you want the animation effects to be rerun.

```
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
    .GotoSlide 3
End With
```

The samples are VBA macros, but the PowerPoint object model is common for all kind of applications. So, I believe you can adapt the property and method sequence into your language of preference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. 
But from which file should I call those methods? ( I implement them in “ThisAddIn” class)

Comment: This is a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.application.slideshowwindows) of the Application class.